# TikZ: How to reverse arrow direction without switching start/end point?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

Assumed we have this MWE from user [Caramdir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29154):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [domain=0:25.1327,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75, -Latex]
        plot ({\t r}: {0.002*\t*\t});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

I want to reverse the arrow head position, so that the arrow tip is located at the inner end of the spiral and directs to the center.

How to do so?

Comment: instead `-Latex` use `Latex-`? however, the result be ugly ....

Comment: You just place the arrow in the other end in the options: `Latex-` -and then you will need to have a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176779/how-can-i-improve-the-look-of-an-arrowhead-at-the-end-of-a-small-radius-arc/176781#176781

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have arrow's head on opposition side of the spiral curve, you only need to change `-Latex` to `Latex-`. However result is quite unexpected (read unusable)  ...

It might be more acceptable solution to move the arrow head close to the end of the spiral. For this you can exploit the package `decorations.markings`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration = {markings,mark=at position .84 with
             {\arrowreversed[black]{Latex[length=1.5mm]}}}
                        ]
\draw[postaction={decorate}]
    plot[domain=0:25,variable=\t,smooth,samples=101,
           {Latex[length=1mm]}-]
        ({\t r}: {0.002*\t*\t});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could mention that you used the position `0.84` because it does not work for much smaller values of the position, e.g. `... at position .14 with ... ` throws a `dimension too large` error. In fact, any position below `.34` has that problem. And then you may want to add that your proposal is, let's say, strongly inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/121799.

Comment: Dear @marmot, my solution is based on example from page 639, TikZ and PGF manual, v 3.1) . I was not aware for mentioned answer, thank you for pointed me to it.  Value `0.84` for arrow head position I determined experimentally, according to my taste (that arrow head is approximately below origin of spiral). Your observation about positioning of harrow head is very good!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would like to argue that bent arrows look better, also in the original plot. But since the curve becomes singular at 0, this does not immediately work because of `dimension too large` errors. However, it does once we approximate the inner-most stretch by an arc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myt}{pi}   
    \draw[{Latex[bend,length=2pt]}-] 
    (0: {0.002*\myt*\myt})
    arc({0}:{180}:{0.002*\myt*\myt});
    \draw  plot[domain=pi:25.1327,variable=\t,samples=75,smooth]
         ({\t r}: {0.002*\t*\t});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is the original pic with a bent arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [domain=0:25.1327,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75, -{Latex[bend]}]
        plot ({\t r}: {0.002*\t*\t});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that one should always load `bending` when one attaches arrows to curved paths, regardless of whether or not one bends the arrows, since otherwise [the paths get distorted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472149/121799). Bending cures the distortion even when not explicitly used.